# How to extract data from one table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I am a new developer and a new user here so let me explain my problem that I have with this SQL script.

I have a table that stores

```
CREATE TABLE test 
(Id int, 
CompanyName nvarchar(200),
BookedDate nvarchar(20), 
BookedTime nvarchar(20), 
Source nvarchar(500), -- is it booked from the enduser website or admin) 
PaymenthMethod  nvarchar(50), 
Cost decimal(10,2))
```

,so this is one table that stores this info.

I need to make a sql server query so I can get info like this:

**enduser** website

```
CompanyName|TotalSales|SalesOnSelectedMonth|SalesViaOnline|SalesOffline(cash)
```

**admin** website

```
CompanyName|TotalSales|SalesOnSelectedMonth|SalesViaOnline|SalesOffline(cash)
```

How to store data from the above table in a same row, grouped by CompanyName(there is like 40 companies)?

Comment: its not clear , provide sample data and desired output

Comment: can you provide more information of the data and your expected query output? you can use http://sqlfiddle.com/ for that

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we have the below data in table TEST:

```
insert into test(ID,COMPANYNAME,BOOKEDDATE,BOOKEDTIME,SOURCE,PAYMENTHMETHOD,COST) values(1, 'company1', '2017-06-22', '21:48:20', 'enduser', 'online',1.2);
insert into test(ID,COMPANYNAME,BOOKEDDATE,BOOKEDTIME,SOURCE,PAYMENTHMETHOD,COST) values(1, 'company2', '2017-05-22', '21:48:20', 'admin', 'cash',100);
insert into test(ID,COMPANYNAME,BOOKEDDATE,BOOKEDTIME,SOURCE,PAYMENTHMETHOD,COST) values(1, 'company4', '2017-04-22', '21:48:20', 'enduser', 'cash',200);
insert into test(ID,COMPANYNAME,BOOKEDDATE,BOOKEDTIME,SOURCE,PAYMENTHMETHOD,COST) values(1, 'company2', '2017-03-22', '21:48:20', 'admin', 'online',500);
insert into test(ID,COMPANYNAME,BOOKEDDATE,BOOKEDTIME,SOURCE,PAYMENTHMETHOD,COST) values(1, 'company3', '2017-02-22', '21:48:20', 'enduser', 'online',700);
insert into test(ID,COMPANYNAME,BOOKEDDATE,BOOKEDTIME,SOURCE,PAYMENTHMETHOD,COST) values(1, 'company5', '2017-01-22', '21:48:20', 'admin', 'cash',800);
insert into test(ID,COMPANYNAME,BOOKEDDATE,BOOKEDTIME,SOURCE,PAYMENTHMETHOD,COST) values(1, 'company6', '2017-12-22', '21:48:20', 'enduser', 'online',800);
insert into test(ID,COMPANYNAME,BOOKEDDATE,BOOKEDTIME,SOURCE,PAYMENTHMETHOD,COST) values(1, 'company8', '2017-11-22', '21:48:20', 'admin', 'online',700);
insert into test(ID,COMPANYNAME,BOOKEDDATE,BOOKEDTIME,SOURCE,PAYMENTHMETHOD,COST) values(1, 'company7', '2017-10-22', '21:48:20', 'admin', 'cash',100);
insert into test(ID,COMPANYNAME,BOOKEDDATE,BOOKEDTIME,SOURCE,PAYMENTHMETHOD,COST) values(1, 'company3', '2017-09-22', '21:48:20', 'enduser', 'cash',200);
insert into test(ID,COMPANYNAME,BOOKEDDATE,BOOKEDTIME,SOURCE,PAYMENTHMETHOD,COST) values(1, 'company1', '2017-08-22', '21:48:20', 'admin', 'online',700);
insert into test(ID,COMPANYNAME,BOOKEDDATE,BOOKEDTIME,SOURCE,PAYMENTHMETHOD,COST) values(1, 'company5', '2017-07-22', '21:48:20', 'enduser', 'cash',100);
insert into test(ID,COMPANYNAME,BOOKEDDATE,BOOKEDTIME,SOURCE,PAYMENTHMETHOD,COST) values(1, 'company1', '2017-06-22', '21:48:20', 'admin', 'online',200);
insert into test(ID,COMPANYNAME,BOOKEDDATE,BOOKEDTIME,SOURCE,PAYMENTHMETHOD,COST) values(1, 'company9', '2017-05-22', '21:48:20', 'admin', 'cash',700);
insert into test(ID,COMPANYNAME,BOOKEDDATE,BOOKEDTIME,SOURCE,PAYMENTHMETHOD,COST) values(1, 'company10', '2017-04-22', '21:48:20', 'admin', 'online',100);
insert into test(ID,COMPANYNAME,BOOKEDDATE,BOOKEDTIME,SOURCE,PAYMENTHMETHOD,COST) values(1, 'company2', '2017-03-22', '21:48:20', 'enduser', 'online',800);
insert into test(ID,COMPANYNAME,BOOKEDDATE,BOOKEDTIME,SOURCE,PAYMENTHMETHOD,COST) values(1, 'company3', '2017-02-22', '21:48:20', 'admin', 'cash',200);
insert into test(ID,COMPANYNAME,BOOKEDDATE,BOOKEDTIME,SOURCE,PAYMENTHMETHOD,COST) values(1, 'company4', '2017-01-22', '21:48:20', 'enduser', 'cash',100);
```

Then the query for the enduser and month JUN-2017, could look like this:

```
WITH TST AS
(
select
  ID,
  COMPANYNAME,
  CONCAT(YEAR(cast(BOOKEDDATE as date)), '-', FORMAT(cast(BOOKEDDATE as date), 'MM', 'en-US')) BOOKEDDATE,
  SOURCE,
  PAYMENTHMETHOD,
  COST  
FROM TEST
)
select
COMPANYNAME,
BOOKEDDATE MONTH_SELECTED,
t.source SOURCE,
ISNULL(sum(cost),0) AS TOTAL_SALES,
(select ISNULL(sum(cost),0) AS SalesViaOnline from TST onl where onl.COMPANYNAME = t.COMPANYNAME and onl.BOOKEDDATE= t.BOOKEDDATE and onl.PAYMENTHMETHOD = 'online' and onl.source = t.source) SALES_VIA_ONLINE,
(select ISNULL(sum(cost),0) AS SalesOffline from TST onl where onl.companyname = t.companyname and onl.BOOKEDDATE= t.BOOKEDDATE and onl.PAYMENTHMETHOD = 'cash' and onl.source = t.source) SALES_OFFLINE
from 
TST T
where 
BOOKEDDATE = '2017-06'
and t.source = 'enduser'
group by 
  COMPANYNAME
, BOOKEDDATE
, t.source
order by 1;
```

And similarly, the query for the admin and month JUN-2017, could look like this:

```
WITH TST AS
(
select
  ID,
  COMPANYNAME,
  CONCAT(YEAR(cast(BOOKEDDATE as date)), '-', FORMAT(cast(BOOKEDDATE as date), 'MM', 'en-US')) BOOKEDDATE,
  SOURCE,
  PAYMENTHMETHOD,
  COST  
FROM TEST
)
select
COMPANYNAME,
BOOKEDDATE MONTH_SELECTED,
t.source SOURCE,
ISNULL(sum(cost),0) AS TOTAL_SALES,
(select ISNULL(sum(cost),0) AS SalesViaOnline from TST onl where onl.COMPANYNAME = t.COMPANYNAME and onl.BOOKEDDATE= t.BOOKEDDATE and onl.PAYMENTHMETHOD = 'online' and onl.source = t.source) SALES_VIA_ONLINE,
(select ISNULL(sum(cost),0) AS SalesOffline from TST onl where onl.companyname = t.companyname and onl.BOOKEDDATE= t.BOOKEDDATE and onl.PAYMENTHMETHOD = 'cash' and onl.source = t.source) SALES_OFFLINE
from 
TST T
where 
BOOKEDDATE = '2017-06'
and t.source = 'admin'
group by 
  COMPANYNAME
, BOOKEDDATE
, t.source
order by 1;
```

Comment: "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression." I got this error

Comment: Can you give me some sample data from BOOKEDDATE column ?

Comment: '2017-07-22'
'2017-07-24'
'2017-07-24'
'2017-07-23'
'2017-07-23'
'2017-07-23'
'2017-07-23'
'2017-07-25'
'2017-07-25'
'2017-07-25'
'2017-07-25'

This is the BOOKEDDATE Column data

Comment: I updated a little bit the queries. Please take a look.